Option "Keep a copy of forwarded email in this mailbox" when shared mailbox is unlicensed?
I have Microsoft Business Basic and I have email account support@MyDomain for receiving emails from our customers. Joe@MyDomain is my account that I use to send/receive emails:

Then I have the Shared Mailbox that looks like below. As you can I see I have the option to select "Keep a copy of forwarded email in this mailbox".
Question: since Microsoft Business Basic only lets me have one email to send and receive email (the email address that I used to open the account) why is it asking me if I can keep a copy in the mailbox?
From my understanding, this email address doesn't have a mailbox. Even when I try to log on outlook.office.com with support@MyDomain, I get the error msg UserHasNoMailboxAndNoLicenseAssignedError.


The option to keep a copy means that if checked, the mail is both delivered to the shared mailbox and is forwarded to the address specified.
If you uncheck this option, the mail is forwarded, but is not delivered to the shared mailbox.
If your idea is to just have multiple emailaddresses, consider removing the shared mailbox, and adding that email address as an alias to your primary mailbox.
EDIT:
Also sidenote based on our comment exchange: A shared mailbox does not require a license. A license is only necessary when you want to use its username and password to directly login to the mailbox.
If you don't set a license, but you make your other user a member of this mailbox (Full Access) in Outlook, the mailbox will automatically appear between now and an hour from now.

Sorry, screenshot is in dutch. Can't get Microsoft to change it to English no matter what I do. But add yourself either through Members or through Full Access permissions.
In webmail, you can use the following url to directly access that mailbox:
https://outlook.office.com/mail/support@mydomain.com
You login with your joe@mydomain.com account.
Alternatively you login to outlook.office.com first with your account, then click on your profile in the top-right, select Open another mailbox, and type support there to open that mailbox in a new tab.

I understand that. The problem is that the support account is unlicensed, so there shouldn't be a mailbox associated to it.

Even if I try to log on outlook.office.com with that email address, I get the error UserHasNoMailboxAndNoLicenseAssignedError.

You are mistaken there. A shared mailbox does not need a license. If you grant yourself access to the mailbox, you can now access it as follows: outlook.office.com/mail/support.mydomain.com It will ask you to login, you login with joe@mydomain.com.

I can log in fine to joe@MyDomain.com. My question is: how can I see the emails sent to support@MyDomain.com? The only way I can see them is when they're forwarded to joe@MyDomain.com (assuming the forwarding option is On).

If the forwarding option is off, then I have no idea how to see the emails sent to support@MyDomain.com.

See the edit. You first give yourself membership of the shared mailbox, then you can access it either from Microsoft Outlook (windows, mac or android/ios app) or through webmail.

Thanks. So the only way I can see the support mailbox is by logging on to my main account and then selecting "Open another mailbox"?

That is one of the ways, yes. Another is by using the direct url or use Outlook mail client.
